# how to make the changes to source .profile permanent

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I am following the following details from another question on this site

> You can add an alias to the command by editing the file `.profile` in your home directory:
>
> ```
> gedit $HOME/.profile
> ```
>
> and adding the following line:
>
> ```
> alias lock='gnome-screensaver-command -l'
> ```
>
> Then from terminal:
>
> ```
> source .profile
> ```
>
> This will activate the alias. From now on, the alias lock In a terminal will have the effect of locking the screen.

But I have to hit source `.profile` every time I open a new terminal. I  want to make this permanent. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include a link to the original post cited in your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After changing the `.profile` file, you have to logout from your account and login, then it will be sourced once automatically.

Also make sure these file does not exist in your home directory:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
```

If you've got these files, the `.profile` will be ignored.

Comment: Alternatively, have `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.bash_login` evaluate `~/.profile`.

Comment: Look also for ~/.bashrc.

Comment: `.bashrc` doesn't have any effect on `.profile` being sourced or not, actually it's `.profile` which sources the `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

`~/.profile` is evaluated (or “sourced”) automatically whenever a new interactive shell is started. The suggestion to run

```
source .profile
```

only refers to shell sessions that were started before the changes to `~/.profile` were made.

Therefore you don't need to do anything in addition for these changes to take effect in new/future shell sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say aliases should go in `~/.bash_aliases` rather then in `~/.profile`, this way you have a nice own file for them and every new opened terminal will have them executed without the need to logout/login.

But to answer you question: To make your changes permanent, you need to do nothing but login once again. `source ~/.profile` won't be needed any more then.